# JQuery Multidimensional JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json

A bit confused here on how to handle this JSON Object.

```
var data = {
    "username": "Test",
    "rating": "none",
    "workers": {
        "Test.DesktopHome2": {
            "score": "2",
            "alive": true
        },
        "Test.M11x": {
            "score": "4",
            "alive": true
        }
    },
    "test2": "This is a Test"
    }
```

I can access the username, rating, and test2 fields just fine, but am A little stumped on how to loop through the "workers" using JQuery. I would like to display each worker in its own table row, with the worker name ie "Test.DesktopHome2" as the first column in the table, followed by the score, and alive. $.each() functionality likes to throw an error. Not sure how to do it in a for loop, and be able to display the key name.

This code throws an "Unexpected Token" Error.

```
var $UserData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var $Workers = $UserData.workers;
$.each($Workers function(i, item) {
    //Do Stuff
});
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using an `array` of `objects` for workers?

Comment: What do you mean by "$.each() functionality likes to throw an error"? I would think `each()` ought to be the right approach here.

Comment: Your `$.each()` is just missing a comma after `$Workers`.

Comment: You are also trying to use parseJSON on an object.  jQuery.parseJSON expects a string and will return null if an object is passed in.

Comment: Missing comma fixed it :), thanks! Guess that's what I get for staring at code for hours and hours. Tunnel vision for the loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, using `$.each()`:

```
$.each(json.workers, function(index) {
    $('#table').append('<tr><th>' + index + '</th><td>' + this.score + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`workers` is an object (using `{}`)  rather than an array (using `[]`).

You can loop it like this:

```
for (var name in workers) {
  console.log(name); // e.g "Test.DesktopHome2"
  var worker = workers[name];
  console.log(worker.score); // e,g, "2" or "4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for-in` loop:

```
for (var key in obj.workers) {
    console.log('Worker: ' + key + ' Score: ' + obj.workers[key].score + obj.workers[key].alive ? ' Alive' : ' Dead');
}
```

Comment: You missed a part in your code.  You should be doing obj.workers[key].score and obj.workers[key].alive.  The general idea is right, though.